# Slow loading of html file in WebView in Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-webview

I am using ViewPager to load same fragment which contains two webviews in my FragmentActivity.

In the fragment I am loading two html files in two different webview. sometimes i may use external javascript to load inside webview.

So, my problem is, When I try to open the activity for first time it smoothly load the html file.

After finishing the FragmentActivity and open again it take too much time to load same html file.

The duration keep on increasing when opening again and again.

Comment: If the length is increasing on each subsequent load then you have issues with your code somewhere. Please post your WebView loading, onCreates and other pertinent parts so we can check it out. As @mayurbhagat says though, you can cache and reuse your initially grabbed data and only get fresh data if it is out of date for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

if html code is fixed you can use load from cache option rather than loading each time from network.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am facing the same issue. I am using multiple webviews in a viewpager to show news detail pages and user can swipe between these pages. This activity is loaded when user clicks on a list item. With every subsequent loading, the time taken is increasing. i am sure it has something to do with code but cant really understand what. Code below:

package com.samples.app.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.samples.app.R;
import com.samples.app.adapters.NewsDetailWebViewPagerAdapter;
import com.samples.app.utilities.NewsPageConstants;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class NewsDetailWebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private NewsDetailWebViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<View> mListWebViews;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> mNewsDetailUrls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_detail_web_view);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int selectedPosition = intent.getIntExtra(NewsPageConstants.KEY_SELECTED_POSITION, 0);
        mNewsDetailUrls = getNewsDetailViewUrls();
        initializeViews();

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mPagerAdapter = new NewsDetailWebViewPagerAdapter(mListWebViews, selectedPosition);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_news_wv_detail);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        mListWebViews = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < mNewsDetailUrls.size(); i++){
            addView(mListWebViews, mNewsDetailUrls.get(i));
        }
    }

    private HashMap<Integer, String> getNewsDetailViewUrls() {
        return NewsListActivity.news.getNewsLinksMap();
    }

    private List<View> addView(List<View> viewList,String url) {
        final Activity activity = this;
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.wv_progress);
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        //WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_news_detail);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }*/
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                activity.setProgress(newProgress * 100);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot load page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        viewList.add(webView);
        return viewList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds the language toggle button to the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news_detail_web_view, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```